# Downvoting questions based on "open-ended" or "subjective"

Tags: discussion

I have very recently asked a question on the "***history* of *lambda expressions* in *Java***". After a while I have seen five downvotes on the question and when I asked why? In a comment, one said the question is "**open-ended**" as it is about "**history**".

Now, I am not very sure whether this question is also going to get the same result. However I am going to ask it. Actually I have plenty to ask about..

1. How does Stack Overflow define the term "open-ended" to its community?
2. The question is about the history/chronology of a particular feature in a programming language. What is the "open-end" that it has?

Why am I insisting on this? One, it has cost me 10 of the reputation points I have earned with a lot of difficulties. I have been using Stack Overflow for years now. I see a lot of accepted answers for questions which has a lot of deviations, slight alterations that needs to be done in order to refine the answers, which I could have discussed with a comment under the answer.

Yet, I still am unable to do it as I need 50+ reputation points to comment anywhere. I somehow managed to go beyond the half way point to that 50+ reputation points milestone and thanks to those downvotes I have fallen behind again.

Two, there's this widely accepted theory in learning. That is when teaching something, follow the chronological order of its evolution, which is the easiest way for most to absorb, process and retain the knowledge. The intention of this question was solely that. And no the question never asks for lengthy, detailed explanations rather some facts, points to read on or may be some links.

I really don't think that this question should be considered as "not a specific programming question, but an open-ended question on history".

Comment: *How does stack overflow define the term "open-ended" to its community?* There is a good description of subjective questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Also note the "Too Broad" close reason: http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 7):

I'm conflicted on this one.

On the one hand, you have a genuinely interesting question with a rich amount of history to go back through, as to why Java never really shipped with lambdas.

On the other hand...not only can that history be *readily* found online, the direct and canonical answer would have to come from an actual Java architect (likely [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) who *has* answered those sorts of questions in the past).

I'll personally say that while the subject matter intrigues me, it's not the sort of question that is readily answerable on Stack Overflow without heaps of Googling.  Answers which are just Googled aren't *great*.

Comment: Just as I suspected, the question already has two down votes.. ;) Anyway, your point that the direct and the canonical answer should actually come from a Java architect is 100% correct. +1 for that...